# Ruby: how to cut out a string bordered by different chars

Tags: ruby, string, svg, split

from pathes from svg like this:

```
d="M 0,0 10,10 z M 10,10 20,20 30,30 40,40 Z"
```

i like to cut out every block that is bordered with "M" or "m" at the beginning and "Z" or "z" at the end.

Comment: This is easy with regexes. Give it a try.

Comment: Sorry for beeing not exactly enough, thought i was.
Avinash yet realized my problem and put in a working answer. 
Thanks.

Comment: yeah, you were quite exact in saying "here's what I need, someone do this work for me".

Answer (score 2):

Use `string.scan` function..

```
> "M 0,0 10,10 z M 10,10 20,20 30,30 40,40 Z".scan(/\bm[^m]*\bz\b/i)
=> ["M 0,0 10,10 z", "M 10,10 20,20 30,30 40,40 Z"]
```